# Google sheets array formula in SUMIFS

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to put in cell B2 single array formula which will fullfill whole table
In column A I have names of people, in first row i have a dates.
Could you tell me how can i change my formula correctly to the array formula?

column name =SORT(UNIQUE(Arkusz2!A:A))

row with dates =TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(Arkusz2!E:E)))

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(Arkusz2!A:A&"|"&Arkusz2!E:E,A2:A9&"|"&B1:I1,Arkusz2!D:D))`

though it might be worth limiting the ranges passed for performance reasons.